# how to filter numbers out of an Text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, replace

I have a stupid Problem within Vue:
I'm getting an Object which looks like this:

```
`{ "description": "this ist our List.\n Our Service includes:\n-1 something\n-2 something else\n and another thing\n"}`
```

how can i filter out the "\n" and the "-1,-2..." and replace them with htm tags, like 
?

I already tried a function, which gets a value like:

```
returnList: function(value){
  value.replace("\n","<br>")
  return value`
```

But it doesnt work for all \n's

Comment: Umm, `return value.replace("\n","<br>")`?

Comment: `returnList: function(value){
  return value.replace(/\n(-\d)+/g,"<br/>")
}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should change this:

```
returnList: function(value){
  value.replace("\n","<br>")
  return value`
}
```

to this:

```
returnList: function(value) {
  value = value.replace("\n","<br>")
  return value;
}
```

Becuase [.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does not change value itself, but return a new value with the changes.

But, will only change the first value anyway. So you could use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string) `value.split("\n").join("<br>")`.

Comment: it will change only first `\n`

Comment: it worked with split and join

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should know that `String.prototype.replace` function returns the result of the replacement.

```js
let obj = {
  "description": "this ist our List.\n Our Service includes:\n-1 something\n-2 something else\n and another thing\n"
};

console.log(obj.description.replace(/\n-[0-9]+/g, "<br>"))
```

Another regex approach: `/\n(-\d)?/g`

Comment: `returnList: function(value){
  return value.replace(/\n(-\d)+/g,"<br/>")
}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regex. Like that: `value.replace(/\/n/g,"<br>")`

Comment: I tried but it replaces just the first \n

Comment: i tried in browser console and it works for me

Comment: @Gawel1908  He might have tried before you put the extra `/g` on..

Comment: it's still working without `g` too

Comment: Without the `/g` it will only replace one..